# How does spring-data-redis get an objectRecord with a Generic type

Tags: spring-data-redis, redis-streams

I want to implement MQ using stream in Redis, and when the entity type passed is generic, my code does not deserialize the entity consumption message correctly.

producer critical code:

```java
    @Bean
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory rf) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> rt = new RedisTemplate<>();
        rt.setConnectionFactory(rf);
        rt.setKeySerializer(RedisSerializer.string());
        rt.setValueSerializer(RedisSerializer.json());
        rt.setHashKeySerializer(RedisSerializer.string());
        rt.setHashValueSerializer(RedisSerializer.json());
        return rt;
    }
    
    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(RedisTemplate<String, Object> rt) {
        return arg -> {
            MyMessage<User> userMyMessage = new MyMessage<User>().setReceiver(1)
                                                                 .setClientType("app")
                                                                 .setPayload(new User().setName("testName")
                                                                                       .setAge(10)
                                                                                       .setId(1));
            Jackson2HashMapper hashMapper = new Jackson2HashMapper(false);
            rt.opsForStream()
              .add(StreamRecords.newRecord()
                                .in("my-stream")
                                .ofMap(hashMapper.toHash(userMyMessage)));
        };
    }
```

the consumer:

```java
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory rcf) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> rt = new RedisTemplate<>();
        rt.setConnectionFactory(rcf);
        rt.setKeySerializer(RedisSerializer.string());
        rt.setValueSerializer(RedisSerializer.json());
        rt.setHashKeySerializer(RedisSerializer.string());
        rt.setHashValueSerializer(RedisSerializer.json());
        return rt;
    }

    @Bean
    StreamMessageListenerContainer.StreamMessageListenerContainerOptions<String, ObjectRecord<String, Object>> hashContainerOptions() {
        return StreamMessageListenerContainer.StreamMessageListenerContainerOptions.builder()
                                                                                   .pollTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                                                                                   .objectMapper(new Jackson2HashMapper(false))
                                                                                   .build();
    }

    @Bean
    StreamMessageListenerContainer<String, ObjectRecord<String, Object>> hashContainer(
            StreamMessageListenerContainer.StreamMessageListenerContainerOptions<String, ObjectRecord<String, Object>> options,
            RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory,
            RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate) {

        var container = StreamMessageListenerContainer.create(redisConnectionFactory, options);
        container.start();
        String group = "default-group";
        String key = "my-stream";
        try {
            redisTemplate.opsForStream().createGroup(key, group);
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
        container.receiveAutoAck(
                Consumer.from(group, "default-consumer"),
                StreamOffset.create(key, ReadOffset.lastConsumed()),
                message -> {
                    log.info("receive message stream:{}, id:{} value:{}", message.getStream(), message.getId(), message.getValue());
                }
        );
        return container;
    }
```

when producer starts, the object is cached correctly in Redis:
[image]

but the consumer does not read the object，The following is the log

```
receive message stream:my-stream, id:1655890663894-0 value:"com.commons.MyMessage"
```

the entity's attributes are gone, How do I make it work? And if I want listen to two different stream (message object types are different) what to do, is to configure two StreamMessageListenerContainer or can be configured in a container.
thanks!

Comment: I know one way is to convert objects to `String` for storage, but is there a better way？